# Retrieve LAST_LOGIN from DBA_USERS using oJDBC

Tags: java, database-administration, oracle12c, ojdbc

I am trying to retreive the **LAST_LOGIN** column from the **DBA_USERS** view, by using oJDBC api.

By executing `DESC DBA_USERS`, we can check that LAST_LOGIN column is a :
 **`TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE`**.

**Update: In order to reply to @steve, my query is this:**

```
SELECT USERNAME, ACCOUNT_STATUS, EXPIRY_DATE, CREATED, LAST_LOGIN FROM DBA_USERS WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS='OPEN' and EXPIRY_DATE >= SYSDATE ORDER BY USERNAME ASC;
```

However, everytime i try to retrieve it from the ResultSet:

```
java.sql.Timestamp tmpstmp = rsAllActiveUsers.getTimestamp("LAST_LOGIN");
```

, i get:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
>   at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:189)

I am using oracle DB 12c, and ojdbc6, and i know that 12c brought this column. Can this be the problem?

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: what is the actual sql statement? it might be worthwhile testing it also with ojdbc7.

Comment: @steve, you can check it on the question! Thanks for the help in advance!